# Understanding process of Jquery, ajax, php and MySQL and function calls

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, jquery-ui, jquery

I am trying to create something similar to what would be defined as dialog box that would appear when the button is clicked and which should show title, random image and button to proceed further with with original request.

```
function custom_display_reminder(theHTML,theDownloadLink){if(typeof jQuery.ui!='undefined'){$("#dialog").attr("title","Please help spread the word").html(theHTML);$("#dialog").dialog({modal:true,width:375,buttons:{"Continue to Download":function(){$(this).dialog("close");window.location=theDownloadLink;}}});}else{window.location=theDownloadLink;}}
function custom_reminder(aelem,topic){theLink=$(aelem).attr("href");
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"/db/ajax.php",
        data:"action=reminder&thepath="+theLink+"&topic="+topic,
        dataType:"json",
        error:function(){window.location=theLink;},
        success:function(msg){if(msg.status==1)custom_display_reminder(msg.html,theLink);
        else{custom_message(msg.message,"error");}}});}
```

I have found the above script on one of the websites that has this particular feature that I am trying to implement, but cannot understand the process. Can someone help me to explain the process and all calls made by that script?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can start with javascript, then jQuery. What you "stole" is a simple process that involves [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) and [jQueryUI](http://jqueryui.com/).

Comment: So your question is: _"can someone give me a one-on-one tutorial?"_

Comment: Thanks for your advise Mihai, but I honestly think that word stole is really inappropriate, since I have not used any part of the script above on my site at all and in fact trying to create similar process without implementing any part of the third party code at all.

Comment: I said "stole" since that code is posted by you here. And exactly like I said, look in [jQueryUI](http://jqueryui.com/) dialogs demos.

Comment: I just need a simple explanation of a few variables and how they are build/requested {theHTML,theDownloadLink}

Comment: @AlexB: Please, read the FAQ of this site, your question _doesn't belong here_. This is a Q&A site, where you post _your own code_ if you're stuck trying to make it work. If you want to know how an ajax call works, use google, use the jQuery documentation, or just a _book_. Don't expect/treat this site as if it were an interactive code generator

Comment: Now Mihai, I have actually got to thank you since this looks like an exact place where I can begin learning. This is exactly what I was talking about since stilling is not my thing.

Comment: @Elias, point taken, but then again you guys are pros and always know better that any search engine, where to start looking or learning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code you posted, theHTML and theDownloadLink are arguments given to the first function from the function you've posted immediately below it (and possibly anywhere else in a script). In this instance it's referring to msg.html for theHTML and theLink which is the href value (a URL) of the specific a tag selected.

$.ajax simply refers to an asynchronous HTTP (or AJAX) request, documentation on it can be found here: [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Further documentation on jQuery to help you on your way can be found here: [jQuery API Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/). Reading and understanding this documentation will better help you understand the code above and make writing your own implementation easier. If you're new to JavaScript in general I strongly suggest searching for tutorials online, or looking at W3Schools documentation.

Comment: Thanks Jamie for trying to help me, much appreciated, I have already began reading all documentation related to Jqeury UI and can now understand lot more than before.

Comment: The part, which I still cannot understand is everything within $.ajax({...}); I just do not get what is being posted and what json object is returned? I know for a fact that on the website that I have this script from the dialog box retunes randomly selected image from 34 possible images. and also what could be within ajax.php file, those are the questions that I still need to find some sort of an answer.

Comment: It's posting the data parameter to the URL as a HTTP POST (accessed in PHP via $_POST['url_parameter_name_goes_here']), the PHP evaluates the data given and returns a JSON object.

Comment: In your case the JSON returned becomes the object known as msg, so if the msg.status == 1 it does one thing, else does another. msg.html I assume contains some form of string containing html which forms the body of a display. In the case of the php giving a totally unexpected response (not JSON), it just sends the user to theLink.

Comment: Thanks again!! So the original href has a urlid attached to it (example.com/file.php?urlid=my_file, when clicked the dialog appears which shows the title "Please help spread the word", randomly selected image (from 34 available variants) right below the title and at the very bottom there is a button "Continue to Download" that when clicked takes you to the landing page example.com/files/my_file_download.html. I wonder what is inside the /db/ajax.php file that created this process?

Comment: All of the images that appear when requested are located inside images/dialog/1.jpg and so on and so forth, but only one is selected per request